# Creating Bounding Box in QGIS

Tags: qgis, pyqgis, point, extents, polygon-creation

I have four coordinates: north, south, east and west. How can I automatically create a bounding box in my shapefile? Can I do it through Python?

Comment: short answer is: YES you can. have a look at https://docs.qgis.org/3.22/en/docs/pyqgis_developer_cookbook/cheat_sheet.html#layers and there you can use the "Layer from WKT" example

Answer (score 3):

Yes. Use this structure:

```
# make new memory layer
crs = 'EPSG:4326' # specify the crs of coordinates
layer = QgsVectorLayer(f"Polygon?crs={crs}", "LAYER_NAME", "memory")
QgsProject.instance().addMapLayer(layer)

# specify coordinates
north = [0, 0]
west  = [0, 1]
south = [1, 1]
east  = [1, 0]

# construct box geometry
geom = QgsGeometry.fromPolygonXY([[
    QgsPointXY(*north),
    QgsPointXY(*west),
    QgsPointXY(*south),
    QgsPointXY(*east)
]])


# make feature
feature = QgsFeature()
feature.setGeometry(geom)

# add the feature to the layer
layer.dataProvider().addFeatures([feature])
```